# how to read mulitiple elements from the same node

Tags: c#, .net, xml

i want to read to nodes from xml
now getting only linktext, want linkurl also.. can u pls help in this

```
lst = targetNode.AncestorsAndSelf().Elements("LinkText").Select(p => p.Value).ToList<string>();


<LeftMenu>
 <linkid>1</linkid>
 <linkurl>www.h1.com</linkid>
      <NavLinks>
        <linkid>2</linkid>
        <linkurl>www.h2.com</Linkurl>
                <nav2>
                   <linkid>3</linkid>
                 <linkurl>www.h3.com</Linkurl>
                 <nav2>
         </NavLinks>
    </leftmenu>
```

Comment: I think showing us an XML snippet might make this question clearer

Comment: They're called siblings and (IIRC) XPath has an entire axis for that

Comment: Huh, there are no LinkText nodes in that XML... Worse, that's not even well-formed XML, because some tags are not closed (XML names are case-sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

You can just grab the LinkUrl elements and add them to the same list:

```
lst = targetNode.AncestorsAndSelf().Elements("LinkText").Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
lst.AddRange(targetNode.AncestorsAndSelf().Elements("LinkUrl").Select(p => p.Value));
```

Comment: its creating new row. it should be same row with two column

Comment: should i change the object type of the list?

Comment: @user: Please update your question with that information (and relevant XML).

Comment: <LeftMenu> <linkid>1</linkid> <linkurl>www.h1.com</linkid> <NavLinks> <linkid>2</linkid> <linkurl>www.h2.com</Linkurl> <nav2> <linkid>3</linkid> <linkurl>www.h3.com</Linkurl> <nav2> </NavLinks> </leftmenu>